# lodash.differenceBy in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two array of object let s say

```
var toto = [
  {a:1, b:2, c:1},
  {a:7, c:2, d:1}
]

var titi = [
  {a:2, b:2, c:1},
  {a:1, c:2, d:1}
]
```

I wanted to find an alternative to `lodash.differenceBy` (which I would like to not implement just for this case)

basically something that do

```
differenceBy(toto,titi, "a")
// => [{a:2, b:2, c:1}]
```

I made a filter with a simple parameters, but I'm struggling to add object

```
static DifferenceBy(arr:Array<any>, arr2:Array<any>){
    return arr.filter(function(i) {return arr2.indexOf(i) < 0;});
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/differenceBy.js

Comment: Isn't the output supposed to be `{a:7, ..}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check any `lodash` method source by going to https://lodash.com & clicking **Source**

For example, go to https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#differenceBy

[image: _.differenceBy]

Answer (score 4):

You could use **[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** like this

```js
const toto = [{a:1,b:2,c:1},{a:7,c:2,d:1}]
const titi = [{a:2,b:2,c:1},{a:1,c:2,d:1}]

function differenceBy(array1, array2, key) {
  return array1.filter(a => !array2.some(b => b[key] === a[key]))
}

console.log(differenceBy(toto, titi, "a"))
```

This returns all the items in `array1` which do not exist in `array2`:

```
{
    "a": 7,
    "c": 2,
    "d": 1
}
```